# Selling event tickets with an initial deposit using either Store or CartThrob?

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, ecommerce

I've previously read it's possible to setup EE for selling tickets for an event using the inventory as the number of tickets for sale, so each product can be used as the event.

However, is it possible to somehow setup the process of buying a ticket so that the customer pays a deposit to confirm their place, then pay the remaining fee at a later date nearer the time of the event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector; we own CartThrob)

You'd need to customize CartThrob a bit to do this, likely with a custom payment gateway. Depending on how far from the event you're selling the tickets, you may also need to make use of your gateway's token/vault function. (If it's close, you could use the "authorize and capture" later function). Either way, you'd need customization though -- because you want two charges, the deposit and the balance.

[Let us know if you can't figure this out](https://www.cartthrob.com/support/index.php?pg=request) and we'd be happy to find a way to help!